# Gradle project sync failed.Basic functionality will not work properly

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I run my project I get this error:`Gradle project sync failed.Basic functionality will not work properly`

LOGCAT:

[image]

This is my `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
#Tue Sep 05 19:53:08 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

This is `build.gradle`(project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is `build.gradle`(Module app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.materialtabs"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/tinydb-0.0.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jipsi.jar')
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    //    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
    compile files('libs/jipsi_055b734e299151494aa487f8b477464882efb509.jar')
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

> Project structure-> Project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Data Binding Library.

To use it, add in your `module/build.gradle` in the `android` block:

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

More [info here.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Comment: i added into android block this but it doesn't work same

Comment: Quite strange. The class DataBindingBuilder is used by Android Gradle plugin. Try to update the SDK Manager and to run the clean task